# Grails Spring - How to initialize Spring project when Grails Application run

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

I have a spring project which I am using as Jar in a Grails 3.0 application. This project is about interacting with the database. How can I initialize a spring project in a Grails 3.0 application?

In tests I have initialize this jar like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring-config.xml"})
public class ScenarioEntityPersistenceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this in `resource.groovy` and problem was solved.

```
beans = {
   importBeans('classpath*:spring-config.xml')
}
```